# Ubuntu 22.04 no wifi after suspend

Tags: networking, drivers, suspend, mediatek

I'm having trouble after resuming my suspended Mini PC. The wifi is not working and it made the whole system unstable. The only way to fix it is by restarting the PC.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and my wifi card is:
`MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz`
using `mt7921e` driver.

Some of the errors I can see in the logs are:

```
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlp2s0' UP

mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000a address=0x0 flags=0x0020]

<error> [1653216123.3592] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
```

I really appreciate someone's help to fix this behaviour.

Comment: Odd as it sounds, the solution that worked for me was disabling/purging ModemManager. I had very similar symptoms as you, but now my system resumes Wifi like a charm.

Comment: Same problem here, I am running Fedora36 (5.18.19-200.fc36.x86_64), still no luck:(